# SQL - LAG() Order By 2 Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

Is it possible to use lag with 2 columns in the order by? If not how would i go about doing this?

Here is what i have now:

```
LAG(GOOD_QTY) Over (Order By SEQUENCE_NO) As Value
```

Here is what i want:

```
LAG(GOOD_QTY) Over (Order By SUB_ID DESC,SEQUENCE_NO) As Value
```

I need the lag to prioritize the Sub_ID because all sub ID operations need to be checked first.

This is a visualization of what i mean/want.

Here is the initial values/table:

```
SEQ_NO   SUB_ID   value  
-------------
10       0         50
30       0        200
20       0         75
25       0        100
10       1        150
20       1        250
```

Here is what i want after the lag function with 2 order by occurs

```
SEQ_NO   SUB_ID   value  
-------------
10       0        250
30       0        100
20       0         50
25       0        75
10       1        NULL
20       1        150
```

So essentially i want to do the lag function with all values that have a `sub_id = 1` separately and before all values with `sub_id = 0`. Once it has done all `sub_id = 1` values it should continue going to the `sub_id = 0` values passing the last value from `sub_id = 1` to the first seq_no with `sub_id = 0`

Just figuring out how to do all the `sub_id = 1` values first and then doing the `sub_id = 0` values is good enough, i can figure out the rest probably.

Comment: Did you try it out? What happened?

Comment: Wait... it worked. LOL

Answer (score 1):

For your desired results using `lag()`, you need to `order by sub_id desc, seq_no`:

```
select seq_no, sub_id
  , value = lag(value) over (order by sub_id desc, seq_no)
from t
order by sub_id, seq_no
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YHCIOD53469

returns:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| seq_no | sub_id | value |
+--------+--------+-------+
|     10 |      0 | 250   |
|     20 |      0 | 50    |
|     25 |      0 | 75    |
|     30 |      0 | 100   |
|     10 |      1 | NULL  |
|     20 |      1 | 150   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

You can also get the same results using `lead(value) over (order by sub_id, seq_no desc)`.

Comment: LOL thanks. i probably should have tried this first before posting this question... it worked exactly as i would expect.